# Resizing jQueryUI widgets

Tags: css, jquery-ui, widget, spinner, uislider

I am relatively new to jquery UI. I am able to understand the functionality and making use of the widgets. However I find the widgets quite large and clunky and would like to resize them. Specifically I am using a large number of spinners, sliders and choice buttons. I would like to resize these to fit my page but can't figure out any way to do this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a css file that comes with the widget, you can edit it, or you can overwrite the rules in you css file.